# Share operationId between two different paths in openapi

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

firt of all, I want to apologyze for my english. It's not my fault but Spanish education system :D.

I've just started with a openapi's migration and I need your help.
I like to use different paths which refer the same operationId.
I explained it with an example:

```
paths:
  "/my-path/my-resource":
    get:
      tags:
        - my-api
      operationId: getMyResource
      responses:
         ...
         [omitted]
         ...
  "/another-path/another-resource":
    get:
      tags:
        - my-api
      operationId: getMyResource
      responses:
         ...
         [omitted]
         ...
```

Is it possible?

Thank very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged `openapi-generator`, but appears to be a general question about the OpenAPI Specification.

Operation IDs must be unique per operation. The Operation object section of the spec [defines](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3.html#fixed-fields-7) operationId as:

> Unique string used to identify the operation. The id MUST be unique among all operations described in the API. The operationId value is **case-sensitive**. Tools and libraries MAY use the operationId to uniquely identify an operation, therefore, it is RECOMMENDED to follow common programming naming conventions.

The bolded "case-sensitive" is taken directly from the spec, but emphasizes an excellent point about passing these specifications through tooling (which is why they must be unique). In openapi-generator, we use operationId to define method or function names in generated output. Many languages don't support overloaded methods and some don't even support non-standard casing (e.g. Go). Our tooling will convert operationId according to the output language, and is therefore more strict in this case than the specification. You can create a custom generator and extend the logic which processes operations if you absolutely need duplicate method names and if your target output supports it.

Comment: The relevant part here is not case-sensitivity but _"The id **MUST be unique** among all operations described in the API."_ So the answer to OP's question is No.

Comment: @Helen thanks, I'd forgotten while answering that OP is a non-native speaker. I've updated my answer to more clearly call out the uniqueness requirement up front, and that the explanation I provided after the spec quote describes why that is.